# Windows: CouchDB crashes during reinstallation

Tags: windows, couchdb

I have a CouchDB installed on a windows machine sometime ago which is working fine and the version was 1.1.0. Now (after few months of first installation) I tried uninstalling the existing CouchDB 1.1.0 and which went successfully but has left the folders '/etc' and '/var' in the installation directory.
Now I am trying to re-install using setup-couchdb-1.2.0_otp_R15B.exe without deleting the above folders. After re-install when I am trying to connect to the DB I get the below error in the log. Please help on what could be the issue...

```
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:36:53 GMT] [error] [<0.108.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
{<0.108.0>,crash_report,
[[{initial_call,{couch_db_updater,init,['Argument__1']}},
{pid,<0.108.0>},
{registered_name,[]},
{error_info,
{exit,snappy_nif_not_loaded,
[{gen_server,init_it,6,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,321}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
{ancestors,[<0.107.0>,<0.105.0>]},
{messages,[]},
{links,[<0.107.0>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{trap_exit,true},
{status,running},
{heap_size,610},
{stack_size,24},
{reductions,672}],
[{neighbour,
[{pid,<0.105.0>},
{registered_name,[]},
{initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}},
{current_function,{proc_lib,sync_wait,2}},
{ancestors,[]},
{messages,[]},
{links,[<0.106.0>,<0.107.0>,<0.93.0>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{trap_exit,false},
{status,waiting},
{heap_size,233},
{stack_size,9},
{reductions,50}]},
{neighbour,
[{pid,<0.107.0>},
{registered_name,[]},
{initial_call,{couch_db,init,['Argument__1']}},
{current_function,{proc_lib,sync_wait,2}},
{ancestors,[<0.105.0>]},
{messages,
[{ack,<0.108.0>,{error,snappy_nif_not_loaded}}]},
{links,[<0.105.0>,<0.108.0>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{trap_exit,false},
{status,runnable},
{heap_size,233},
{stack_size,16},
{reductions,43}]}]]}}
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:36:53 GMT] [error] [<0.93.0>] To open the database `_users`, Apache CouchDB must be built with Erlang OTP R13B04 or higher.
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:36:53 GMT] [error] [<0.103.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
{<0.103.0>,crash_report,
[[{initial_call,{couch_auth_cache,init,['Argument__1']}},
{pid,<0.103.0>},
{registered_name,[]},
{error_info,
{exit,
{{badmatch,file_exists},
[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,380}]},
{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,352}]},
{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,217}]},
{couch_auth_cache,init,1,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,123}]},
{gen_server,init_it,6,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,297}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]},
[{gen_server,init_it,6,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,321}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
{ancestors,
[couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.35.0>]},
{messages,[]},
{links,[<0.101.0>,<0.104.0>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{trap_exit,true},
{status,running},
{heap_size,1597},
{stack_size,24},
{reductions,284}],
[{neighbour,
[{pid,<0.104.0>},
{registered_name,[]},
{initial_call,
{couch_event_sup,init,['Argument__1']}},
{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
{ancestors,
[couch_auth_cache,couch_secondary_services,
couch_server_sup,<0.35.0>]},
{messages,[]},
{links,[<0.103.0>,<0.96.0>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{trap_exit,false},
{status,waiting},
{heap_size,233},
{stack_size,9},
{reductions,32}]}]]}}
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:36:53 GMT] [error] [<0.101.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
{<0.101.0>,supervisor_report,
[{supervisor,{local,couch_secondary_services}},
{errorContext,start_error},
{reason,
{{badmatch,file_exists},
[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,380}]},
{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,352}]},
{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,217}]},
{couch_auth_cache,init,1,
[{file,
"d:/relax/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_auth_cache.erl"},
{line,123}]},
{gen_server,init_it,6,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,297}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
{offender,
[{pid,undefined},
{name,auth_cache},
{mfargs,{couch_auth_cache,start_link,[]}},
{restart_type,permanent},
{shutdown,brutal_kill},
{child_type,worker}]}]}}
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:36:53 GMT] [error] [<0.89.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
{<0.89.0>,supervisor_report,
[{supervisor,{local,couch_server_sup}},
{errorContext,start_error},
{reason,shutdown},
{offender,
[{pid,undefined},
{name,couch_secondary_services},
{mfargs,{couch_secondary_sup,start_link,[]}},
{restart_type,permanent},
{shutdown,infinity},
{child_type,supervisor}]}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you'd hit [COUCHDB-1482](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1482) issue. Try to install more [recent CouchDB release](http://couchdb.apache.org/#download) (or [1.2.2](http://archive.apache.org/dist/couchdb/binary/win/1.2.2/) if you'd like to stay on 1.2.x branch) that has snappy issue fixed.

Also, try to make clear CouchDB install: move your `etc` and `var` dirs somewhere, uninstall CouchDB and remove remain files, install CouchDB and move your `var` data back. Instead of moving old `etc` on top of new one, you have to backport your config changes from `local.ini` file manually (don't override `default.ini` file!) to be sure that there wouldn't be any config collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am currently trying upgrading to 1.2.2 and testing it out.